# Simple Summation Question

Tags: summation

I don't know why I'm confused this elementary stuff, but is the following correct?

$v_{1}v_{1}^{*} + v_{1}v_{2}^{*}... + v_{1}v_{n}^{*} + v_{2}v_{1}^{*} + v_{2}v_{2}^{*} ... + v_{2}v_{n}^{*} + v_{n}v_{1}^{*} + v_{n}v_{2}^{*} + ... + v_{n}v_{n}^{*} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}v_{i}v_{j}^{*}$

where $v^{*}$ is the conjugate of the vector $v$?

Comment: that's correct!

Comment: Yes, your expression is correct. In general, for any two vectors $v$ and $w$ in a complex vector space, the product $vw^*$ represents the entrywise product of $v$ and the conjugate of $w$. The expression you provided is the sum of all possible pairwise entrywise products between the vectors $v_i$ and their conjugates $v_j^*$ for $i, j = 1, \dots, n$. To write it in a more compact form, you can use the double summation notation: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n v_i v_j^*$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to see
if we write it in a series of steps.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=v_{1}v_{1}^{*} + v_{1}v_{2}^{*}... + v_{1}v_{n}^{*} + v_{2}v_{1}^{*} + v_{2}v_{2}^{*} ... + v_{2}v_{n}^{*} + v_{n}v_{1}^{*} + v_{n}v_{2}^{*} + ... + v_{n}v_{n}^{*}\\
&=v_{1}v_{1}^{*} + v_{1}v_{2}^{*}... + v_{1}v_{n}^{*}\\
&\quad + v_{2}v_{1}^{*} + v_{2}v_{2}^{*} ... + v_{2}v_{n}^{*}\\
&\quad ...\\
&\quad + v_{n}v_{1}^{*} + v_{n}v_{2}^{*} + ... + v_{n}v_{n}^{*}\\
&=(v_{1}v_{1}^{*} + v_{1}v_{2}^{*}... + v_{1}v_{n}^{*})\\
&\quad + (v_{2}v_{1}^{*} + v_{2}v_{2}^{*} ... + v_{2}v_{n}^{*})\\
&\quad ...\\
&\quad + (v_{n}v_{1}^{*} + v_{n}v_{2}^{*} + ... + v_{n}v_{n}^{*})\\
&=(\sum_{j=1}^n v_{1}v_{j}^{*})\\
&\quad + (\sum_{j=1}^n v_{2}v_{j}^{*})\\
&\quad ...\\
&\quad + (\sum_{j=1}^n v_{n}v_{j}^{*})\\
&= \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}v_{i}v_{j}^{*}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: It's probably even easier to see if you go the opposite way ;)

Comment: True, but I wanted to start with the original expression. I generally dislike writing expressions with "..." as you can see if you look at some of my answers.